# MIPS32 - Load a half-word using only load word and store word instructions

Tags: memory, assembly, mips, memory-address, instructions

For educational purposes, I need to figure out how to load a half-word from a memory address to a register using only the lw and sw instructions in MIPS.

**I am aware you can use lh, sh, lb, and sb but I want to know how to do it with only lw and sw.**

For example, load the two bytes "AB" into register $t0:

```
Mem: [ A ] [ B ] [ C ] [ D ]
      100   200   300   400

$t0: [ 0 ] [ 0 ] [ A ] [ B ]
```

My solution so far:

```
lw  $t0, 100($zero)
srl $t0, t0, 16
```

Is there a way to do the same operation using *only* sw and lw instructions and **no other operations**?

Comment: I had an idea involving loading and storing words at half word boundaries... but at least `spim` throws an exception for attempting to do that. So my immediate thought is no, this cannot be done with just `lw` and `sw`.

Comment: `lw` and `sw` are defined in the MIPS ISA to cause an address error exception when the address is not word-aligned.  I agree that what the OP proposes can't be done with just `lw` and `sw`

Comment: What about `swl` or `swr`? You could do some tricks with that...